# Migraciones en symfony

Tags: symfony

Estoy con las migraciones en symfony y me esta saltando el siguiente error al realizar migraciones.

Necesito ayuda para solucionar el siguiente error.

WARNING! You are about to execute a migration in database "formaciondipba" that could result in schema changes and data loss. Are you sure you wish to continue? (yes/no) [yes]:

> 

[notice] Migrating up to DoctrineMigrations\Version20220914114129
[error] Migration DoctrineMigrations\Version20220914114129 failed during Execution. Error: "An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'areas_profesionales' already exists"

In ExceptionConverter.php line 45:

An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'area
s_profesionales' already exists

In Exception.php line 28:

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'areas_profesionales' already exists

In Connection.php line 69:

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'areas_profesionales' already exists

doctrine:migrations:migrate [--write-sql [WRITE-SQL]] [--dry-run] [--query-time] [--allow-no-migration] [--all-or-nothing [ALL-OR-NOTHING]] [--configuration CONFIGURATION] [--em EM] [--conn CONN] [--] []

Gracias de antemano

Comment: De los errores que te da se deduce que en tu esquema actual ya existen las tablas que quieres migrar. Es como si la migración quisiera crear esa tablam Puedes mostrar el código de esa migracion? La migración que da problemas es `Version20220914114129`

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, gracias igualmente

Comment: Perfecto. Por favor, pon la solución que has usado como respuesta, así la gente que llegue después pueda tener una solución.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIÓN:

Ejecuto el comando php bin\console make:migration y se crea la migración y luego php bin\console doctrine:migrations\migrate y me migra toda la base de datos.

En caso de salir error hay que eliminar las migraciones y en el archivo de la migración que nos quedamos eliminar las sentencias de SQL que tengamos repetidas, por eso sale el error que ya están creadas ya que está intentando crear unas tablas que ya existen.